# Ionic background image

Tags: html, css, cordova, ionic-framework

I am using Ionic. Currently I am running my test app in chrome with the "ionic serve command". Tried to add a background image to one of my nav views (using the side menu template) but somehow the image is rendered below my app not as the background. Here is my code:

**Style.css:**

```
.login {
    background: url(../img/BG_login.png) no-repeat center center fixed; 
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

**View:**

```
<ion-modal-view class="login">
    ...
</ion-modal-view>
```

This is how it is looking:

[image]

It should cover the entire backgorund and not below my form...

Comment: Can you make a fiddle to recreate it? Maybe because its center vertically and the area is so big? It works fine when i test it.

Comment: Give that background class to `ion-content`.